# One of my flags might be stuck in limbo

Tags: support, flagging, specific-answer

I flagged an answer about 5 days ago, and the post has since been deleted, but the flag is still there and is listed as pending. I think when the post got deleted, the flag might have been messed up? I'm not sure how this works, but my flags have always been answered within a couple days at the most.

I don't even know how I would link you to the flag, since the post it refers to has been deleted. However, the flag was in regard to an answer of the following question: [How to fight an army of skeletons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/161280/how-to-fight-an-army-of-skeletons/161472#161472)

---

If I have misunderstood something about how this system works, I apologize. And if it just so happens that no one has gotten around to my flag yet, I apologize for seeming impatient.

Answer (score 5):

We currently have a not insignificant (for world building anyway) backlog of flags.  I can tell from your display name you are aware of all the...stuff going on with SE.  Most of the moderators on the site are marked inactive right now in protest.

We are keeping an eye on flags for stuff that needs immediate attention but everything else is basically being ignored. We don't like impacting the community like this, lets hope things get sorted out soon.

Comment: Yup, this. For context, the flag queue is . . . maybe 4-6 times as large as it normally is. I don't remember it being this backlogged in my nearly four years of moderating the site. Nor do I personally have plans to change that.

Comment: I just referenced this deficit in my post about editors in meta. I agree with the moderator strike... that’s a more formal relationship with SE than general editing!

Comment: @HDE226868 I note that you’re also on the Mythology SE. I posted a question in their meta last week about what kind of questions they accept. Would you mind giving it a glance?

Comment: @SRM-ReinstateMonica I'll take a look soon, yeah. Feel free to poke me if I don't get to it in a day or two.